# amp-list within amp-consent element not always working

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Generally I wanted to implement an amp-consent following this tutorial:

[basic user consent](https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/basic_user_consent_flow/)

But for some reason the elements which should be loaded via amp-list do not always appear within the amp-consent element.

As long the amp-list block is placed outside the amp-list its contents is visible immidiatelly.

Why is this so and how to display the amp-list contents along with the prompt-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently AMP has some build-in restriction on generating results with amp-list without specifying any particular action, but you may solve this just by triggering one. 
Admitted it is not the best solution but it works.

Just add another div-Element inside your amp-consent component and place for example an button (which displays another div container) within the source div container.

```
on="tap:targetContainer.show,sourceContainer.hide"
```

Depending on Service which you have applyed and the result volume, the list generated by the call to your end-point should be visible right now.

```
<div id="targetContainer" hidden class="message">    
    <amp-list width="auto" height="132" layout="fixed-height" src="yourEndPoint" class="m1">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
           <button class="button_select" on="{{onAction}}">{{label}}</button>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
```